# How to enable VSync synchronization in processing 2.x?

Tags: java, opengl, processing

Previously, in processing 1.x, I used the following code to enable VSync synchronization:

```
void enableVSync()
{
    frameRate(-1);
    GL pgl = (PGraphicsOpenGL)g;
    gl = pgl.beginGL();
    gl.setSwapInterval(1);
    pgl.endGL();
}
```

This does not work in processing 2.x and I can't seem to find out how or even if it is supposed to work in processing 2.x.

**Edit:**

By switching from `size(500, 500);` to `size(500, 500, P2D);`, it seems to help. It now looks like processing does all the drawing in a back buffer and switches it to the front buffer at the VSync.

However, the `draw()` function is still asynchronous with the vsync and even though I don't see any tearing anymore, there's still motion stuttering whenever a frame is skipped or drawn twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, `frameRate()` in `PJOGL` actually runs `setSwapInterval()` though with some strange logic regarding the value set ([github](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/99f5f08f928f78a7c260cf688cbb476122e83c58/core/src/processing/opengl/PJOGL.java#L228)). A workaround for this is:

```
void setup()
{
    setup(500, 500, P2D);
    frameRate(-1);                                      // set unlimited frame rate
    ((PJOGL)PGraphicsOpenGL.pgl).gl.setSwapInterval(1); // enable waiting for vsync
                                                        // before swapping back/front buffers
}
```

**EDIT:**

For Processing 3, I use the following:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.media.opengl.glu.GLU;

void setup()
{
    frameRate(-1);
    beginPGL();
    GLU.getCurrentGL().getGL2().setSwapInterval(1);
    endPGL();
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

For Processing 3.2, the following seems to work:

```
void setup()
{
  fullScreen(P3D);
  frameRate(1000);
  PJOGL pgl = (PJOGL)beginPGL();
  pgl.gl.setSwapInterval(1);
  endPGL();
}
```

Comment: In processing 3.0.2 I get the following error: "cannot make a static reference to the non-static field PGraphicsOpenGL.pgl".

Comment: I've added an edit about more recent versions of processing/PJOGL